# Weird Spark SQL behavior while selecting column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe from which I'm trying to select the columns. Weirdly I'm getting following exception.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`products.n_52`' given input columns: [products.objectives, products.q_4, n_8, n_52, q_52, npv_4, n_4, b_1, products.qpv_8, qpv_13, q_4, b_26, products.npv_1, products.qpv_52, products.q_26, products.q_52, npv_52, n_13, products.n_4, products.qpv_1, products.b_8, npv_8, qpv_4, b_13, b_4, qpv_8, q_26, b_8, products.qpv_26, n_26, products.qpv_13, qpv_52, npv_13, products.b_1, products.b_13, products.n_13, q_13, products.b_4, n_1, q_8, products.q_8, qpv_26, products.npv_52, products.b_52, products.npv_13, products.npv_26, products.n_1, products.npv_4, qpv_1, npv_1, products.npv_8, products.qpv_4, custid, products.n_52, products.n_26, products.q_1, b_52, products.product, products.n_8, npv_26, q_1, products.q_13, products.b_26];;
```

Spark gives me error that a the column `products._n_52` does not exist in the given list but I can see that column in the give list.

Has anybody ever experienced similar issue ?

**If its of any help I'm passing this column in a UDF like below**

```
df = df.withColumn("arr", F.explode(F.col("products.n_52"))
```

Comment: Could you please provide code which creates df?

Comment: @dytyniak I read it from parquet files. Also the problem was that column name had a `.` in it, which was causing the issue.

Comment: So, did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes, removing/replacing  `.` solved the issue.